# Profiler reports ServiceBase.Run causing high CPU usage

Tags: .net, service

I've developed a fairly complicated Windows Service in .NET (running on the 2.0 CLR) which I noticed consumes a lot of CPU cycles, effectively maxing out one of the machine's cores.

I attached a profiler (SlimTune) that reported that over 90% of CPU cycles were spent in `ServiceBase.Run`. My service appears to otherwise be running fine, it creates about 9-15 other threads that were all blocked in `EventWaitHandle.WaitOne` or `Stread.Read` calls (by design) and are functioning fine, I have no loops in the program code that would cause a CPU burn, so something's amiss with `ServiceBase.Run`.

I took a look with reflector and I can't see any loops in the `Run` method call tree, and my Service's `Start` method completes and returns control to its caller.

My code is simple, making it a mystery why it's jamming:

```
public static class Program {

    public const String ServiceName = "FooService";

    public static void Main(String[] args) {

        using(FooService service = new FooService()) {

            ServiceBase.Run( service );
        }
    }
}

public partial class FooService : ServiceBase {

    private FooServiceImplementation _fooService;

    public FooService() {

        this.ServiceName = "FooService";
    }

    protected override void Dispose(Boolean disposing) {
        base.Dispose( disposing );
        if( disposing ) {

            if( _fooService != null ) {
                _fooService.Dispose();
                _fooService = null;
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStart(String[] args) {

        try {

            // Load configuration.
            LoadConfiguration();

            // DO NOT CALL Config.Trace before Config has loaded, because the ExceptionsPath isn't yet set.
            // TODO: Use the temp directory if ExceptionsPath is not set.
            if( Config.DebuggerBreakOnStart ) {

                Debugger.Break();
            }

            Config.Trace("[OnStart] LoadConfiguration() complete.");

            _fooService = new FooServiceLoop();

            Config.Trace("[OnStart] _fooService instantiated.");

            _fooService.Start();

            Config.Trace("[OnStart] _fooService.Start() complete.");

        } catch(Exception ex) {

            Config.LogException( ex );

            throw;
        }
    }

    // Other methods omitted for brevity
```

My logs show that `Config.Trace("[OnStart] _fooService.Start() complete.");` is being called and the `OnStart` method is being returned from.

Comment: Have you tried the Visual Studio profiler?  If so, with what sort of results?

Comment: @PeterRitchie the service runs on a machine that doesn't have Visual Studio installed, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ServiceBase.Run` method tells the system to start all your `ServiceBase`-derived instances (or `FooService`, in your case).  It does this by setting up some structures then calling the native `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher` function.  This function goes into a wait state processing service control messages and passing them on to your `ServiceBase`-derived instances, where applicable.  What this means is that because ServiceBase.Run is the first method executed and does not exit until all other code is completed and disposed, it will appear to be the longest-running method in the entire app.  This is a misnomer because it spends most of its time in a wait state not using CPU, waiting for service control requests.  SlimTune tell you *time* spent in a method (as % of time spent in a thread, see the QuickStart section in the CHM file) which is just subtracting the time the method exited from the time it started.  This is not the same as CPU cycles used.  At 90% this means that code in your service really only used 10% of the total time running.

Unless you're not returning back from `OnStart` right away, spending a lot of time in `OnStop`, or spending a lot of time processing other service control requests `ServiceBase.Run` is not using much in the way of CPU cycles.

Note: the the system disposes your `ServiceBase`-derived objects before it exits from `ServiceBase.Run`.  So, you don't need to put your `ServiceBase`-derived instances within a `using` statement.  I don't think this is causing you any issues; but that could result in an `ObjectDisposedException`.

Comment: Thanks! Can you suggest a tool or technique for identifying the cause of the CPU hogging?

Comment: @Dai Well, that's the thing.  What the profiler is really telling you is the time the service ran because ServiceBase.Run is really the entry-point, it will always run about as long as your service runs.  Unless you stop the service sooner, there's no way to have ServiceBase.Run use less time.  There's nothing you can do about that and ServiceBase.Run isn't using CPU (it's just the duration between when ServiceBase.Run was called and started your service and when your service exited).  That's the nature of an I/O-bound method: uses little CPU and waits for things to happen.

Comment: Right, but as I said, my service spawns about 15 other threads. Is there any way to find out which of those threads is jamming the CPU?

Comment: @Dai I'd suggest looking at the metrics for each of the entry points for the threads.  The profiler should detail those.  Some profilers will let you ignore the I/O bound methods (you have to decide which are I/O bound); but I don't think SlimTune will...

Comment: I was able to get VS installed on the server. I attached to the service and Froze every Thread and Thawed them individually until I saw CPU usage spike. I found it's a thread that's actually sitting in an `EventWaitHandle.WaitOne()` call that never returns. Do you know how `WaitOne` could be hogging the CPU?

Comment: Ah, I forgot to Thaw that thread too. It looks like it's running in a tight-loop without actually resetting the EventWaitHandle so that `WaitOne` will actually wait. I'll do a bit more investigation but if so, you'll get the Answer and coveted Bounty for pointing me away from the wrong answer :)

Comment: `WaitOne` would never hog CPU, it puts the thread into a wait state relinquishing CPU and waiting until the `EventWaitHandle` is signalled again.  Normal operation.  This is only a problem if the `EventWaitHandle` is never signalled again.

Comment: I verified the issue was an `EventWaitHandle` that wasn't being `Reset()` correctly - just that every time I paused the process the thread was coincidentally in `WaitOne()` so I assumed it was working properly. Bounty awarded :)